# Mathematical Induction: First vs. Second order Induction Axiom

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, cardinals, peano-axioms, second-order-logic

The second-order variables in the second order Induction Axiom of (second order) Peano Arithmetic range over the set of all subsets of the natural numbers,
that is, it has uncountable cardinality. Does the induction scheme on first order Peano Arithmetic has also uncountable number of instances?

Answer (score 4):

No, it has countably many instances: the set of finite strings from a finite (or countable) alphabet is countable. In that sense, there are "fewer".

But note that there is **only one** second-order induction axiom: it just has a variable ranging over all subsets, but that does not make it uncountably many separate axioms any more than $\forall n(S(n) \neq 0)$ is infinitely many axioms.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hence, the (single) Second order Iinduction Axiom is strictly stronger than the first order induction schema (countably many axioms).

Comment: While that is true, it does not follow from the "hence". The reason is deeper.

Comment: Second-order arithmetic, as a second order  theory, is categorical (in contrast with first order) and that is a real strength! (in my opinion). Above I concentrated in the range and the expressive power of the Induction Axiom